# Восстановить отображение git ветви в toolbar phpstorm

Tags: phpstorm

Случайно скрыл отображение текущей рабочей ветви `git`. Где находится настройка отображения `git` ветвей?

Comment: `Alt+9` ? или вам что другое нужно?

Comment: @МихаилРебров нет это не то. Мне необходимо отображать **имя текущей** ветви.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы **скрыть/отобразить** текущую рабочую ветку **git** в **PhpStorm** необходимо правой кнопкой мыши кликнуть по `toolbar`. Откроется попап с настройками. Кликаем по `Git Branch`

Тулбар(`toolbar`):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]